# How to echo an image according to the value in the database?

Tags: php, database, echo

I have 3 group of images, productimage, productimage2, productimage3.
Some product have image in all 3, but some only have 1 or 2 images.
Those with 1 or 2 images, will produce an extra empty box.

this is my echo coding,

```html
<?php 
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage"] . "'>"; 
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage2"] . "'>"; 
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage3"]. "'>"; 
?>
```

How can i code it to echo only when there is a image in it? I have tried if statement, but i failed.

Comment: simple if\else logic, only echo if `$product[ "productimage"]` exists\not blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($product[ "productimage"]))
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage"] . "'>"; 
if (!empty($product[ "productimage2"]))
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage2"] . "'>"; 
if (!empty($product[ "productimage3"]))
echo "<img class='productimg' src='img/" . $product[ "productimage3"]. "'>"; 
?>
```